# How to choose a file and save the path's file via JS

Tags: javascript, html, web

I want to click on a button to open a window and choose a file.
I'm using this code for the choosing:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('file-input').click();">Open</button>
<input id="file-input" type="file" name="name" style="display: none;" />
```

How can I save the path? (For example `c:\temp\song.mp3`)

I dont need to download the file. it's a local file.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't.

Comment: But why would you want to save a file?

Comment: i want to save the path and after to do somethig with the file. run some function on the file.

Comment: You can't modify user files with JS.